# Rank and Nullity of 2 linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $A$ in $L(V)$ be given. What is the dimension of the following subspaces in terms of $\dim (V)$ , $\operatorname{nul}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)$?

a) $U_1= \{B \in L(V) : AB = 0\}$

b) $U_2=\{B \in L(V) : BA = 0\}$

c) Prove that if $\dim V =10$ and $\operatorname{rank} (A) =4$, then there are non-zero operators $B$, such that $BA = AB =0$.

I know $B$ is not $\ker (A)$ although $AB = 0$; for example, if $B=[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ b_1 \ b_2 \ b_3]$ and $A = [a_1 \  a_2 \ a_3 \ a_4\  0 \ 0 \ 0 ]$ then there are some values of $AB$ that are zero, and some that are not.

However, I don't know how to argue. 
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, but think of it like this, for $U_1$, we have

$$ x \to Bx \to A (Bx) \to 0 $$

we have that $Bx \in \ker A$, we also have for $U_2$

$$ x \to Ax \to B ( Ax) \to 0$$

So $Ax \in \ker(B)$. Now we want to $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2) \neq 0$ so there are operators $B$ with this property. So let's use the rank nullity theorem. We're given

$$A : V \to W \quad s.t. \quad rank(A)+nul(A)= \dim(V) \implies 4 + 6 = 10$$

For a) we have $\dim(U_1) = nul(A) = 6$, for b) we have $B$ takes any element to $0$ but we don't want that, we should only take $B(0) \to 0$ so $Ax = 0$ which means that $\dim(U_2)= nul(A) =6$. But this means

$$ 10=\dim(V) \geq \dim(U_1 \cup U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) - \dim( U_1 \cap U_2) = 12 - \dim(U_1\cap U_2) $$

$$\implies \dim( U_1 \cap U_2) \geq 2$$

Comment: Thank you so much. You mean dim U1= dim U2 =6? Oh, I got you.

Comment: Yes about the $\dim$ thing and also, To deal with the dimension of $U_2$, I know it has to be at a minimum of $6$, but not sure of it's exact dimension :S

Comment: Nvm, it is 6, forgot how this stuff worked for a second